# LaTeX Font too Small Displayed on Enthought Canopy

Tags: ipython, enthought

I just found that the mathematical expression (LaTeX) displayed on Enthought IPython Notebook is barely to see. Is there any way to customize it?

I use Enthought Canopy 32 bit, academic license on Window 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right Click on some math expression > `Math Settings` > `Scale All Math...`.

Persistent on a per-browser Basis, based on cookie.